# Elementor Mega Menu drop down won't close on Anchor Links

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Hi I have a Elementor Mega Menu with one of the items being a anchored link (#pi-process).
The dropdown Navigation would not close by itself when pressed on the link. But closes when pressed on a link that leads to a different page.

I tried adding a custom jQuery and Javascript to hide the dropdown container when clicked on the menu item id 'e-n-menu-item-title-1303'. But it doesn't work.

Any ideas, the drop down is massive so its taking-up massive part of the view-port and its not a good user experience for a user to close the menu to see what's underneath

```js
// Find the link and menu items content div
var link = document.querySelector('#e-n-menu-item-title-1303 a');
var menuItemsContent = document.querySelector('.e-n-menu-items-content');

// Add click event listener to the link
link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the link from navigating

  // Remove the "e-active" class if present
  menuItemsContent.classList.remove('e-active');

  // Apply "display: none" to the menu items content
  menuItemsContent.style.display = 'none';
});
```